# Calculating logarithm, why is this algorithm not efficient, and how to make it more efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm

I was wondering if I could calculate the logarithm of a number based on a number relative to a base (for example, log base 2 of 16) without actually using `log()`. I managed to do it, but I don't believe it is very efficient.

This is my code in Python:

```
def myLog(x,b):
    exp=0
    ans=b**exp
    while x!=ans:
        ans=b**exp
        if ans==x:
            return exp
        exp=exp+1
```

So I could give it `myLog(16,2)` and it should return 4. And indeed it does, however I believe it is not the most efficient way, so how could I fix it and make my code more efficient, not just in this case, but in most of them?

Comment: This is an almost perfect fit for codereview.SE ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my two cents worth:

```
def myLog(x,b):
    exp = 0
    ans = 1
    while ans<x:
        ans *= b
        exp += 1
    if ans == x:
        return exp  
    else:
        raise ValueError("can't find a suitable exponent")

In [10]: myLog(16,2)
Out[10]: 4
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hmn... i tested it however it does not seem to work for some reason

Answer (score 4):

Try recursion:

```
def func(a, b, ans=0):
    if a/b == 1:
        return ans + 1
    else: return func(a/b, b, ans+1)

In [26]: func(16, 2)
Out[26]: 4

In [27]: func(8, 2)
Out[27]: 3

In [28]: func(16,4)
Out[28]: 2
```

Comment: `max(None,0)` is cleaner than the ternary here

Comment: Or how about `ans = ans or 0`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Actually, now that I think of it, there's no reason to use a `None` default at all. Just make the default value 0 and don't mess with it later.

Comment: can't `if a/b==1:` simplify to `if a==b:`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not taking into account if someone gives a negative value such as myLog(-1,2) or if it is 1 myLog(1,2), then you compute ans before the loop which you know it always be 0 because you put exp = 0, then in the loop you compute it again without before changing the exp.

[logarithm](/questions/tagged/logarithm) [python](/questions/tagged/python)

Answer (score 1):

Assumes:

```
x: a positive integer
b: a positive integer; b >= 2
returns: log_b(x), or, the logarithm of x relative to a base b.
```

Seems the shortest way is:

```
def myLog(x, b):
    ans = 0
    while b <= x:
        ans += 1
        x /= b
    return ans
```

Or recursively:

```
def myLog(x, b):
    if (b > x): return 0
    else: return 1 + myLog(x/b, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an [endless loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop):

```
def myLog(x,b):
    exp = 0
    ans = b**exp
    while x != ans:
        ans = b**exp
        if ans>x:
            return -1
        if ans == x:
            return exp
        exp = exp+1
```

See also:

- *[What algorithm is used by computers to calculate logarithms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/what-algorithm-is-used-by-computers-to-calculate-logarithms)*
- *[Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)*

Answer (score 0):

This version adds support for non-integer outputs:

```
def log(a, b):
    b = float(b)
    a = float(a)
    g = a
    n = 0
    i = 1
    while b**i != 1:
        while g >= b**i:
            g /= b**i
            n += i
        i /= b
    return n
```

Comment: Note: This is only accurate when `a >= 1` and `b > 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
    def log(a, b):
b = float(b)
a = float(a)
g = a
n = 0
i = 1
while b**i != 1:
    while g >= b**i:
        g /= b**i
        n += i
    i /= b
return n
```

Does not work for all numbers. log(5,10) returns 0.00000 when it should be 0.69897